# Implement a cross-thread call check

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to check that a method is called from the same thread that instantiated the class similar to the feature implemented by a WinForms Control.

How can achieve this? is the following example valid?

```
public class Foo
{
  int ManagedThreadId; 
  public Foo()
  {
    ManagedThreadId=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
  }

  public void FooMethod()
  {
    if (ManagedThreadId!=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Foo accessed  from a thread other than the thread it was created on.");

    //Method code here.
  }
}
```

Im not so sure that storing the ManagedThreadId is enough to achieve this.
If i store a reference to the Thread, can this create problems to the GC or to something else?

Comment: That looks ok - the `ManagedThreadId` doesn't vary over time ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), so you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ManagedThreadId` should be fine for this task, the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for `Thread` states that it doesn't vary over time.

After looking at the reference source for the WPF window [verifies its not used across threads](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs#31852a8904b66b47#references), I think it is also okay to keep a reference to the `Thread` your class is instantiated on, as that's [what it does](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs#fdcfbb9383a20825): storing a `Dispatcher` which in turn keeps a reference to its `Thread`.

Comment: If the `Dispatcher` achieve this storing a reference to the `Thread` and not just the `ManagedThreadId` i think is better to do in the same way.Thanks

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello I suspect that this is because storing the ID leaves open the possibility that the thread creating the object is destroyed and a subsequent thread is given the same ID.  Exceedingly unlikely, but, I suppose, possible in a long-running application that creates and destroys lots of threads.