# How do I detect multi-threaded use?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it sufficient to compare the `ManagedThreadId` at the time an object is created and at the time a method is called to verify that it isn't being used in a multithreading scenario?

```
public class SingleThreadSafe
{
    private readonly int threadId;
    public SingleThreadSafe()
    {
        threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    }

    public void DoSomethingUsefulButNotThreadSafe()
    {
        if(threadId!=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "This object is being accessed by a thread different than the one that created it. " +
                " But no effort has been made to make this object thread safe.");
        }
        //Do something useful, like use a previously established DbConnection
    }
}
```

My intuition is often wrong about threading, so I wanted to check to see if there are edge cases I should be keeping in mind.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just make sure your object is thread safe?

Comment: The parallel task library makes it easy for anyone on the team to write code that may indirectly or directly be using a non-thread safe object, for example, executing the same ADO.NET command on 3 threads (there will be a race to set parameters) or sharing the same connection (all sorts of races).

Comment: Suppose someone creates the object on background thread 42 that is subsequently destroyed.  Then the program creates a new background thread 43.  There's no reason 43 can't use the object.  Do you really want to require that the object also be destroyed and a new one created?  The design you're trying to achieve would require that.

Comment: Matthew, that sounds like a code review issue, not a code issue. Either don't have objects that aren't thread safe, or don't use threads, or make sure when you use threads, you only use thread-safe objects.

Comment: This seems like a very restrictive condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement a cross-thread call check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950876/implement-a-cross-thread-call-check)

Comment: re: is this duplicate... Too bad questions can't be merged, my question got a different set of answers, most of which disagree with the other question's answers!

Comment: I think moderators (or 20K+ users?) can merge questions and their answers if they're closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not sufficient !

A managed thread id *can be reused* by the CLR, so `if(threadId!=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)` can return `false` even is the calling thread *is* different from the one used to construct the object.

What you are trying to achieve is possible through references comparisons:

```
if (!object.ReferenceEquals(Thread.CurrentThread, ThreadThatCreatedThis))
// ...
```

EDIT :

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says however that :

> The value of the ManagedThreadId property does not vary over time, even if unmanaged code that hosts the common language runtime implements the thread as a fiber.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Actually it is possible to do this - e.g. by comparing references to threads (as the WPF Dispatcher does).

Answer (score 1):

That's basically what Windows Forms does. Here's a snippet from `Control.InvokeRequired` (quoted from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/d3ab1956c1b4c3db.html)):

```
public bool InvokeRequired {
    get {
        using (new MultithreadSafeCallScope())
        {
            ...
            int hwndThread = SafeNativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
            int currentThread = SafeNativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId();
            return(hwndThread != currentThread);
        }
    }
}
```

If comparing thread IDs is good enough for Windows Forms, I suppose it'd be good enough for me...

Comment: Right now there is one exception to the SystemThread==ManagedThread paradigm, that being CLI code being hosted in a SQL Server instance running fibers.  WinForms probably doesn't care about that exception.

Comment: That makes sense when the underlying object (like Win32 GUI resources) inherently belong to an OS thread. It doesn't necessarily translate to arbitrary user-defined classes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid it doesn't.

For similar scenarios I'm using [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or [Thread Local Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: How would using ThreadStatic detect if it were being used by different threads?

Comment: `ThreadStatic` works only for static variables, so it won't work in that case. Here is sample with ThreadStatic - https://dotnetfiddle.net/25PoIJ but for static variables. You can save some variable state, and then it can be checked. But only for static field

Comment: Like store the locally created instances in a threadstatic collection, and check if it contains...